# Setting Highcharts Series and Category data dynamically

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Im trying to update a chart via an AJAX call using the following code

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#filter").click(function () {
        BuildReport();
    });

    $j("#container").highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'SEs open by Group',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            min: 0,
            allowDecimals: false
        },
        xAxis: {},
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                            'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {}
    });

    BuildReport();
});

function SetChartSeries(series) {
    debugger;
    chart = $j("#container").highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(getReportCategories(series));
    chart.series = $j.map(series, function (item) {
        return {
            name: item.Name,
            color: item.Colour,
            data: $j.map(item.Items, function (list) {
                return {
                    name: list.Category,
                    y: list.Value,
                    id: list.ID
                };
            })
        };
    });
}

function getReportCategories(data) {
    var catArray = [];
    $j.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $j.each(value.Items, function (index, value) {
            if ($j.inArray(value.Category, catArray)) {
                catArray.push(value.Category);
            }
        });
    });

    return catArray;
}

function BuildReport() {
    $j.ajax({
        url: "ChartDataHandler.ashx",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            SetChartSeries(data.Series);
        }
    });
}
```

When the page loads or the filter button is clicked BuildReport calls the handler and passes the series data to SetChartSeries. From here I can see that the chart properties are set, but the chart is never drawn. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Did you try to change the AJAX method to POST?

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to be the problem. The data is coming back fine from the AJAX call. Previously I was creating the chart with the series and category properties in the success handler of the ajax call and this worked fine, but would rather just create the chart once and then update the categories and series data with each new ajax call

Comment: I've had some headaches until I understood a bit more how Highcharts works. Maybe redraw the chart? chart.redraw()

Comment: Use `chart.addSeries(object)` when creating chart, and `chart.series[index].setData(array)` when setting you data. `chart.series = .. ` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create new series you need to use [Chart.addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29) method

If you want to set new data in an existing series you need to use [Series.setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29) 
method.

As I see, you create new series for each request and use `addSeries` method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set category data dynamically, you need to use Axis.update() method

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({categories:arrayname,tickInterval:20},true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I did to dynamically update series. The default behavior will redraw the chart. Check https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

```
$('#YourContainer').highcharts().update( {
    series:[{
      name: 'New Legend',
      data: [{
          name: 'New Category',
          y: data
      }]
    ]}
})
```